# Cannot find module './lib/BufferMaker' when use buffermaker in Meteor 1.5.1

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have encountered a problem when use some npm package in Meteor (version 1.5.1), any help on it will be much appreciated.

#### My Environment:

- **meteor**: *1.5.1*
- **buffermaker**: *1.2.0*

#### What I Did:

1. Create a sample Meteor app.

> meteor create test

2. Install *buffermaker*

> meteor npm install --save buffermaker

3. Import *buffermaker* in Meteor app by editing `test/client/main.js`, add line:

> import { BufferMaker } from 'buffermaker';

Full content of `test/client/main.js`:

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { BufferMaker } from 'buffermaker';

import './main.html';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
  },
});
```

4. Run the Meteor app

> meteor npm install
>
> meteor

I got this error in the console of browser (Chrome).

```js
modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './lib/BufferMaker'
    at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:241)
    at index.js (modules.js?hash=e9fc8db…:1016)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:238)
    at main.js (main.js:1)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:238)
    at app.js?hash=3f48780…:101
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
import BufferMaker from 'buffermaker';
```

Some if not most modules do a default export meaning that you don't need the curley braces in your import statement

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, i have tried this, but not work. This module doesn't use default export.

Comment: When I import it in the `test/server/man.js` as: `import { BufferMaker } from 'buffermaker'; ` there is no problem. I don't why I can't import it in client side js.

Comment: BufferMaker is likely not supported on the browser (just like Buffer) without browserify since its a node module. Use http://browserify.org/. to get it working in your browser

Comment: According to Meteor, Browserify is supported by default in 1.5.1. Do I need to use browserify myself ?  https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#client-npm

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `buffermaker` re-exports it’s main module in a strange way, so first step is to bypass it by importing `BufferMaker` directly:

```
import BufferMaker from 'buffermaker/lib/BufferMaker';
```

Then you’ll find when you call `.make()`, it will complain about `Buffer` not existing. To get Buffer on the client, first install `meteor-node-stubs`

```
$ meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs
```

Then load the `buffer` module and stick it on the window so `BufferMaker` can access it

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
window.Buffer = Buffer;
/* OR do it with require */
window.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
```